# Binding viewmodel/model to a real data model

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I'm new to MVVM and WPF itself. I need to do some prototyping in WPF and reached conceptual question.

Suppose you have server which sends you data. Regardless of whether you displaying that currently or not you need to store it in cache, this is your "real data" and at some time you will need to put it on UI (when user opens particular screen), this is your viewmodel.

My question is quite obvious - should I bind UI to a real data stored in some service or should I do a viewmodel wrapper around that data and bind to it? 
In the first case I receive "The calling thread cannot access this object" exceptions unless I use Dispatcher, but calling Dispatcher in model doesn't look right

In the later case I will need to:

1. copy 90% of the data from "real model" to wrapper
2. manually watch changes in underlying "real data" to update viewmodel which in case implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it is most appropriate, is to have your ViewModel pretty similar to your View's needs. It means if your View has a list, then you most likely will need at lease 2 properties on your ViewModel, one for the ItemSource and the other for the selected Items.

Regarding the real data stored, I would say, put it being accessed by your service. Maybe you use the WPF or Silverlight, so you will be protecting your true physical data. And may exchange, just the proper information the view requires.

I hope it helps. If you would like to share some arquitectural aspects of your project, we might give you more advices.

Comment: Thank you, Rafael. I'm doing pretty much the same. The only question which is left - how to:
a) make UI aware of changes in POCO itself and
b) avoid copying too many data fields from POCOs to UI objects

Comment: You may create a project for the repository, access it using your service, you might also create a conversion between the data your ViewModel requires and your true POCO data. So there will be two sides, the "database" like side and your "View" like side. This converter will be the ruler. If you are using Entity Framework, that I think you are. It would be nice to create a generic helper to do the CRUD for you.

Answer (score 1):

I do prefer to have the Data cache in what I call the 'service layer' (the client side code that actually interacts with the server via WCF or whatever communications mechanism).

the data cache is actually several `List<T>` and I do not listen for change notifications in there, because that is actually not needed.

Instead, you consume these 'client side services' from your ViewModels, and retrieve the `List<T>` and store the items in the ViewModel in an `ObservableCollection<T>`. This way you can have two way binding from the View to the ViewModel, with no need for the View to interact with the 'lower level' data cache stored in the 'service layer'.

You do not need to use the Dispatcher when performing ViewModel operations, and therefore this is a better scalable approach because you can do whatever multithreading is needed to retrieve the data.

Comment: Right I went the same way, but assume your cache consists of List<CacheObject>, if on service layer you modify one of the CacheObject, you'll receive "The calling thread cannot access this object" exception. How you awoid this? Thanks!

Comment: Nop. my cache is a list of Entities (customer, product, order, etc). those are POCO objects and have no thread affinity, you recieve that error because you try to modify UI objects in a different thread.

Comment: Okay, we are moving closer. Yes, my objects were not 100% POCO - in fact they were POCO but with INotifyPropertyChanged interface. If I make them just POCO then I loose ability to hear about their changing, do I?